# Kivy: how to make each buttons play different sound

Tags: python, audio, kivy

So I'm writing a drum pad:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader


class GridAction(Button):
    pass


class MakingGrid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MakingGrid, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(16):
            grid_action = GridAction()
            grid_action.bind(on_release=self.button_pressed)
            self.add_widget(grid_action)

    def button_pressed(self, button):
        print('pressed')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MakingGrid(cols=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

There is a grid of buttons as a result, and the purpose is to make them sound different, but I don't know how to do this. Please, help. Thanks in advance) Also, if you see any disadvantages in this code, please, tell me about them, I`m a beginner.

Comment: And what did you do to make some sound ? You have varaible `button` in `button_pressed` why do you use it ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to play audio is with kivy's [soundloader](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.audio.html).

Beyond this, I'm not clear on what your question actually is. The general answer is to do something like give each GridAction its own audio_file property holding a filepath to the sound you want, and bind the on_press events to play the sound at this location.